# How to list all usages of a gradle module

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

I have a project with multiple modules (gradle modules) and some are depend on some others, for example `:modules:backend:core` has a project dependency on `:modules:libraries:util:core` and some others.

In my gitlab CI job I am able to tell when there are changes within some module (e.g. `:modules:libraries:util:core`) by listening to something like `modules/libraries/util/core/**/*`, and then triggering a build of that changed module.

Now the issue I have is how to figure out where this module is used, so that I can build the other side also (in this example I would need to build :modules:backend:core once :modules:libraries:util:core is changed).

Is there some way to list all usages of given module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-dependency-graph-generator-plugin

You can use this plugin to create "your project module dependency graph"

> ./gradlew generateProjectDependencyGraph

[image: app module dependency graph]

or "whole dependency graph".

> ./gradlew generateDependencyGraph

You can find this file from `app/build/reports/dependency-graph` and `app/build/reports/project-dependency-graph` directory.

The folder includes three files: `png`, `svg` and `dot`.
In the `dot` file, you can get the module dependency.

```
":app" -> ":base" ["style"="dotted"]    
":app" -> ":moduleA" ["style"="dotted"]
":moduleA" -> ":base" ["style"="dotted"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle performs [incremental builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html), so telling it to build everything will actually build only the changed parts.